# How to create solr core on centos

Tags: solr

I installed a `Solr 8.1.1` on a `centos 7`, openJdk11 and want to create a new core. But on creating i get an error message:

```
ERROR: Error CREATEing SolrCore 'myCore': Unable to create core [myCore] Caused by: null

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad or unsupported pattern: java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter$ClassicFormat@53ea7249"
```

Comment: How are you attempting to create the core? What is the full stack trace? When does the error you're showing above occur?

Comment: I use: `solr create -c myCore`

Comment: What is the error log generated by your Solr server? Are you providing any configuration directories when creating the core?

Answer (score 0):

Sample API to create a core is as mentioned below.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=coreName&instanceDir=path/to/dir
&config=config_file_name.xml&dataDir=data
```

Using SolrJ API it would be someting like as below.

```
  String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
  HttpSolrClient client = new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl).build();

  CoreAdminRequest.Create createCore = new CoreAdminRequest.Create();
  createCore.setCoreName(core);
  createCore.setConfigSet( coreName);
  createCore.process(client);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, somehow it is related to openJDK. I installed oracleJDK and set it as default java using

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

and selected oracleJDK home as default then used

```
solr create -c myCore
```

It worked for me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNzR9.png)